# Access Shared Variable in Threading

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety, threadpool

I am using below code and using Task.Run inside foeach loop so that each loop can run in parellel because I have some logic inside the foreach loop which take some time, but the problem I am facing is that tContext.SecondNodeId = otherNode; is sometimes printing as 10 or 11 , I want to print that in sequence like first 10 then 11 because I have some code further for which those values matters for logic.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TempData tContext = new TempData();
        var nodes = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
        var otherNodes = new List<int> { 10, 11 };
        foreach (var node in nodes)
        {
            tContext.firstNodeId = node;
            List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
            foreach (var otherNode in otherNodes)
            {
                Task t = Task.Run(() =>
                {
                   
                     tContext.SecondNodeId = otherNode;
                    Console.WriteLine("First Node id is" + tContext.firstNodeId + "Second Node Id is " + tContext.SecondNodeId);
                    // I have some long running code which uses first node and second node id.
                });
                tasks.Add(t);
            }
            Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
        }
    }
}
```

Please suggest a way to achieve.

Below is Output.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Inside the inner loop you call
`Task t = Task.Run(() =>...);`

Which runs the lambda on another thread. Inside this lambda you are setting:

`tContext.SecondNodeId = otherNode;`

and then reading from this value. Because you have multiple threads writing to this value, it can chenge between the values 10 and 11 depending on how long they take to execute. In other words, the inner loop can execute multiple iterations before your spawned task has executed. This is what's known as a "race condition".

So let's say the first inner loop iteration executes, and the task gets to the point of setting `tContext.SecondNodeId =10`. After this line it is completely possible that the second iteration of the loop will have just completed and the spawned task will have set this to 11. Then when the rest of the first task executes it will use the value 11 instead of 10.

A workaround would be to use a local variable:

`var secondNodeId = otherNode;`

And use this in your lambda. This can't be accessed by other tasks and won't change.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, if I will use the local varaible I cant use my object property which i would like to set tcontext.secondnodeId.. Can we achieve it using lock or any other way so that i can use my class object.

Comment: You can return a value from your task and then use this to set the value. An alternative is to create a lock object and lock around the point at which you modify the variable. Note this, would need to be a single lock object used by all the tasks that modify it, so probably could be created at the start of the method.

Comment: I tried using lock but still I can see two of the ids are same ..
 private static readonly object ob = new object();


 lock (ob)
                        {
                            tContext.SecondNodeId = otherNode;
                        }

Comment: You'd have to post the full code to show how you're accessing the variable for me to say why it's not working.

Comment: https://codeshare.io/5PZDXP shared code in this link

Comment: The `Console.WriteLine("First Node id is" + tContext.firstNodeId + "Second Node Id is " + tContext.SecondNodeId);` would need to be inside the lock. Or you pull `tContext.SecondNodeId` out to a local variable (eg. use `otherNode` instead of this) for when you need to read, and only lock on the write like you have done.

Comment: Console.WriteLine("First Node id is" + tContext.firstNodeId + "Second Node Id is " + tContext.SecondNodeId); this line I cant use it inside the lock because after this line of code I ahve some other long running code which is using tContext.SecondNodeId then complete code need to be inside the lock ?

Comment: Perhaps it would be best to post the full code? But to answer, from what I can see you'd need to refactor to use a local variable in the rest of the code or move all the reads/write to `tContext.SecondNodeId` into the lock.